# Android :: TCP Packets

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

I am trying to communicate with my Minecraft server on the RCON port.

I have little clue how to use the sockets & streams stuff though.
Poking around, I found they all have something in common. Socket, InputStream & OutputStream.

I tried it in my code, but the return says nothing useful.
I know  the code actually sends a packet out, because I get an acknowledgement from the server console **[Rcon connection from: /1.2.3.4]**.

Its just the code I tried to assemble based on the interwebs returns something like **[B@4053f750** from output. No idea what that is, nor can I search it in Google.

Can someone give a good site for explaining this stuff?

Thanks a bunch.

```
Socket s;
InputStream i;
DataInputStream iD;
OutputStream o;
DataOutputStream oD;

OnClickListener listenA=new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        try{
            s=new Socket("MyDomain.tld", 12345);
            i=s.getInputStream();
            iD=new DataInputStream(i);
            o=s.getOutputStream();
            oD=new DataOutputStream(o);

            byte[] data=new byte[1024], packet={
                (byte)0xFE, (byte)0xFD, // Magic bytes
                (byte)0x09,                 // Challenge type
                (byte)0xde, (byte)0xad, (byte)0xbe, (byte)0xef  // Your ID token
            };


            o.write(packet);
            i.read(data, 0, 1024);

            guiMain.setTxt_Edit(encodeCArray(data.toString())); // returns a hex string to an edit box. I can then compare the packet to what I expect.

            s.close();
        }catch(UnknownHostException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: `[B@4053f750` is the useless `toString()` of an array of bytes. Use `java.util.Arrays.toString(data)` to have a nicer output.

Comment: You need to check the return of  "i.read(data, 0, 1024);" as it may return different amount if read bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try instead:

```
guiMain.setTxt_Edit(encodeCArray(new String(data)))
```